# How to make the card items always have the same size with flexbox css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm try to create a list with all itens, but i want that itens always have the sime size regardless the content they have in side the card, i tried this

```css
.GridContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.GridCard {
  background-color: bisque;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div className='GridContainer'>
  {Prods.filter(item => item.Categoria === value).map(item => (
  <TabPanel value={item.Categoria} index={item.Categoria}>
    <div className='GridCard'>
      <h1>{item.Nome}</h1>
    </div>
  </TabPanel>
  ))}
</div>
```

but on the screen it looks like this
[image]

Comment: remove `flex-grow: 1;`

Comment: <div className='GridContainer'> should be <div class='GridContainer'> you can use flex-grow to keep same size of flex box

Comment: I tried to remove the flex grow, but they keep with different sizes

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add width property to giftCard ex: `width:100px`

Comment: If I add a fixed size of 100px it will lose responsiveness, is there any way to make it adjust to the screen size?

Comment: sure `width: 10vw`  and you can calculate items in the row and change the width accordingly like `width: calc(100%/5)`